# What's the coefficient of the term?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi everyone I have a problem, I can't find the coefficient of $c_{1}^{2}c_{2}^{2}c_{3}^{2}$ in this expression $(c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3})^{2}(c_{1}^{2}+c_{2}^{2}+c_{3}^{2})^{2}$

It's in a discrete maths exercise if this helps.
It seems like Newton's binomial but I can't find a solution

Comment: Just think how to get $c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2$ from the $c_i$ and $c_i^2$ in the given product.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$(c_1+c_2+c_3)^2=c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2+2c_1c_2+2c_1c_3+2c_2c_3$$

and similarly, we have

$$(c_{1}^{2}+c_{2}^{2}+c_{3}^{2})^{2}=c_1^4+c_2^4+c_3^4+2c_1^2c_2^2+2c_1^2c_3^2+2c_2^2c_3^2$$

Now let's think about what we get from multiplying both equations. The $c_1^2$ in the first equation goes with $2c_2^2c_3^2$ to give $2c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2$. Similarly for $c_2^2$ and for $c_3^2$, so that we already have $6c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2$.

Now about the other terms of the first equation, it is rather clear that we can not get $c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2$ out of them (as multiplying them with one of the term ofthe second equation will lie an odd exponent for at least one of the $c_i$).

Hence, the coefficient you are looking for is just $6c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2$, as there are no other possibilities.

Comment: Typo in the last sentence.

Comment: Thank you @YvesDaoust .

Answer (score 0):

Note that the right factor can only generate terms with squares, so we need only consider the square terms generated by the left factor.

Hence the terms involving $c_1^2,c_2^2,c_3^2$ simultaneously are

$$c_1^2\,2c_2^2c_3^2+c_2^2\,2c_3^2c_1^2+c_3^2\,2c_1^2c_2^2.$$

---

For your curiosity,

$$c_1^6+4c_1^3c_2^3+4c_1^3c_3^3+3c_1^2c_2^4+6c_1^2c_2^2c_3^2+3c_1^2c_3^4+2c_1c_2^5+4c_1c_2^2c_3^3+2c_1c_2c_3^4+2c_1c_3^5+4c_1c_3^2c_2^3+2c_1c_3c_2^4+c_2^6+4c_2^3c_3^3+3c_2^2c_1^4+3c_2^2c_3^4+2c_2c_1^5+4c_2c_1^2c_3^3+2c_2c_3^5+4c_2c_3^2c_1^3+2c_2c_3c_1^4+c_3^6+3c_3^2c_1^4+3c_3^2c_2^4+2c_3c_1^5+4c_3c_1^2c_2^3+2c_3c_2^5+4c_3c_2^2c_1^3$$